# Script using PyMySQL raises error after several hours of proper operation

Tags: mysql, python-3.6, digital-ocean, pymysql, discord.py

so I have a discord bot that uses the `discord.py` `library`. It's running on a `PVS (DigitalOcean, Ubunto)`. The bot reads and writes a lot from the `MySQL` database that is also on the PVS. The problem that has always persisted is that after several hours of proper operation, this error pops out.

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 0] Error)")
```

I tried looking online on why this happens, but it's very confusing and I already tried multiple "supposed solutions", such as changing the interactive time, but that did not work.

I have this written for the pymysql connection:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = "USER", 
                       passwd = "*******", db = "DATABASE", port=3306)
```

Please help!! 
Thanks in advance.